# Format a date in a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, date

I used in my flow a custom field of type date which returns to me in the email action a value of the date in the form of month Daye , Yers , what I want is to have the value of the date in the form DD/MM/YY , I created a formula type resource and I added in date type "date" and in the formula my custom field , but I still have the same display
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a date variable in the flow.
Now Suppose your variable is `originalDate`.

Your formula will be for storing date as MM-DD-YYYY will be -

```
TEXT(MONTH(originalDate))+ "-" + TEXT(DAY(originalDate))+ "-" + TEXT(YEAR(originalDate))
```

Play around this to get your desired result.

PS: Formula field will be of the type text and showing date as text on flow will be easier, for storing it to salesforce use the same originalDate field.

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: is there a way to make the date is it is 13/5/2022 to appear like 13/05/2022 ?

Comment: Take your date in a separate variable of the flow. And create another formula field to add 0 in front of your date if your date is < 10, else it will stay as it is.

Say the variable you are storing your date is originalDate(Number), then - 

var parsedDate = originalDate < 10 ? '0' + originalDate : originalDate ;

Here parsedDate is a string variable. Though the above is an apex code block you can try the same logic in flow. This should work for you.

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev, you can use the LPAD function to add leading zeros. `LPAD(TEXT(MONTH(originalDate)), 2, "0")`.